# Why can't I use Pandas with attribut fetchall in Python-Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm using Python 3.5 with Flask, Flaskext Library to connect with db
I used `pandas` library to normalize data in database

In this case I want to show the result of query normalization from table in database

This is a code in app.py

```
@app.route('/normalisasi')
def normalisasi():
    connection = mysql.connect()
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT rumah_tangga, niaga_kecil, niaga_besar, sosial_umum, sosial_khusus, pemerintah, tnipolri, industri_kecil, industri_besar, target FROM tb_dataset", connection);
    normalisasi = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())*0.8+0.1
    data = pd.fetchall()

    return render_template('normalisasi.html', data = data)
```

And this is a  part of code in normalisasi.html page

```
<tbody>
     {% for item in data %}
     <tr>
      <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[4]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[5]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[6]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[7]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[8]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[9]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[10]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

When I open the page the result like this

[image: The result in browser]

But in console it works

[image: The result in console]

How to fix this, please help me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `fetchall()` is not a pandas method at all, but rather a method on the db cursor. You are very likely not executing the same code when running in console.

You are also not using the `df` nor the `normalisasi` variables for anything.

Normally one would do something like:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: oh i see, but where should i put the code "normalisasi = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())*0.8+0.1]" on your code solution. because i want to normalize the data in db